# Transform comma separated strings to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have this string:

```
var string = "value:50,type:doctor,";
```

What I want to happen is make this into JSON format:

```
{
 "value": 50,
 "type": "doctor"
}
```

in which `value` and `type` is constant, but their value changes.
but `value` always has an integer value while `type` always has a string value.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using split around the "," to separate out the words and then again splitting them ":" to form the keyes and values of the final object.

```js
var string = "value:50,type:doctor";
var obj = string.split(",").reduce((acc,ele) => {
                let key = ele.split(":")[0];
                let value = ele.split(":")[1];
                acc[key] = value;
                return acc;
                }, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Please don't post answers when the OP clearly shows zero effort. You're just doing his/her work